# Do custom events propagate up the component chain in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Custom events didn't propagate in Vue 2. Is there a change in Vue 3 because, as the following example shows, it looks like custom events bubble up the component chain:

```js
const Comp1 = {
  template: `
    <button @click="this.$emit('my-event')">click me</button>
  `
}

const Comp2 = {
  components: {
    Comp1
  },
  template: `
    <Comp1/>
  `
}

const HelloVueApp = {
  components: {
    Comp2
  },
  methods: {
    log() {
      console.log("event handled");
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(HelloVueApp).mount('#hello-vue')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="hello-vue" class="demo">
  <Comp2 @my-event="log"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, by default they now fall through in VUE v3

**You need to define `inheritAttrs: false` to prevent that**

[link to docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-misc.html#inheritattrs), though it doesn't seem to indicate that it affects the events too. It just mentions attributes, but events are part of attributes(`$attrs`).

```js
const Comp1 = {
  template: `
    <button @click="this.$emit('my-event')">click me</button>
  `
}

const Comp2 = {
  components: {
    Comp1
  },
  template: `
    <Comp1/>
  `,
  inheritAttrs: false 
}

const HelloVueApp = {
  components: {
    Comp2
  },
  methods: {
    log() {
      console.log("event handled APP");
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(HelloVueApp).mount('#hello-vue')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="hello-vue" class="demo">
  <Comp2 @my-event="log"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Just as a side note: This solution works because [`listeners` are now passed as part of `$attrs`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/functional-components.html#single-file-components-sfcs) which is why they now fall through. Because `inheritAttrs` has been `true` by default [since version 2](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs).

Comment: You explained why my code works but I think the answer to my question should be no, custom events do not propagate and the code works just because listeners are passed down (in `$attrs`) by default in Vue 3.

Comment: sure, I'll highlight that part o fthe answer

Comment: @Daniel This stops work if we add any emit to Comp1. In this case `my-event` wouldn't be propagated. Could anybody explain why?

Comment: This was driving me nuts, thanks @Daniel!

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle the event into Comp2 :

`<Comp1 @my-event="this.$emit('my-event')"/>`